# SQL concat two fileds into time to calculate TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following table

Agenda

-hour_begin
-minute_begin
-hour_end
-minute_end

Note: All these fields are varchar(2).

I need to calculate the difference in minutes between (hour_begin/minute_begin) and (hour_end/minute_end)

This is what I have tried so far, but without success.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(hour_begin.''.minute_begin),CONCAT(hour_end.''.minute_end)) AS diff
```

This keeps returning an error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, you should mention _what_ error you are getting. Secondly, `TIMESTAMPDIFF` wants date or datetime expressions. If you have times only, `TIMEDIFF` would be the correct function to use. And last but not least, just writing hours and minutes directly after another is not a valid time format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the number of hours * 60, then add the number of minutes.

Something like this:

```
select (60*(hour_end - hour_begin)) + 
  (minute_end - minute_begin) 
from your_table
```

Comment: Great way to archive it. Simple and works like a charm! Thanks